# Пропала цена на страницах товара Woocommerce

Tags: php, javascript, woocommerce

Пропала цена товара на карточках товара. Как на вариациях, так и без. Следом перестали работать кнопки кол-ва.
https://rekate-medical.ru/product/peha-haft/
Заранее благодарю за помощь

Answer (score 1):

В настройках вариаций надо выбрать вариант по умолчанию

Answer (score 0):

Я проверил на телефоне, но цена есть.[image][image][image]  Это может быть связано с найстройками, например убрал цену или она не записалась.

Comment: У этого товара одна цена. В вариациях она не выводиться(

Comment: @GonJol попробуй пересоздать товар.

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло(